# How to reset/block $_POST reset by backwards of browser

Tags: php, database, http-post

I'm trying to create a quiz with Form submit and $_POST.

**Step 1.** User should verify with e-mail first and then can play quiz.

**Step 2-a.** If user select correct answer, then user will be send to next-quiz-page.php.

**Step 2-b.** If it's wrong, then user will be send to failed-page.php.

**Step 3.** The status will be saved in database, when they win or lose. Therefore user who already played, can not play it again.

I did it until here with this method $_POST:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['quiz_start']) ) {
// quiz start
} else {
// quiz can not be loaded
}
```

Here is the problem:
when i click a "backwards" in **Step 2**(next-quiz-page.php, failed-page.php) of browser, then i can back to the quiz-page again and i can play quiz again. Because the value of $_POST still are there. Of course when i submit, i will get error message because the database already has the data which is already "played".

Is there any way to reset $_POST by clicking backwards of browsers?

Comment: when the form is submitted, you can empty the $_POST values or unset the $_POST['quiz_start'].

Comment: @Sachin that would unset them within the currently running script instance only. It doesn't prevent the browser form sending them again, if the form gets re-submitted (either due to page reload, or explicit user action.)

Comment: @Sachin i thought it. Besides, i already tried to use: unset($_POST('quiz_start')); but it doesn't reset it, when i come back to the quiz page by clicking backwards.

Comment: Then you can add one more condition in if ( isset( $_POST['quiz_start']) && empty($already_record_exist) ). check this value - $already_record_exist from database.